# Installing Windows SDK .net 4.5 in a Windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net-4.5, gacutil

I was trying to install Windows SDK which supports .NET 4.5 in a Windows 2008 server. But I couldn't find any link for the same. All I could find was this:

[Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310)

Can't we install SDK which supports .NET 4.5 in a Windows 2008 server, do I have to upgrade to Windows 2012 server? I could see that .NET 4.5 framework supports Windows 2008 server but not sure about the SDK. The reason I am looking for this is because, I am trying to install an assembly using GACUTIL, but when I install Windows SDK and try running GACUTIL, it states that the version is different.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I was installing wrong SDK, I was installing SDK for 7.1, I should actually install SDK for 8.1. Silly mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much for returning to answer your own question - I was stumped on this for hours with failed installations and registry hacks trying to do what I needed without this installer. I figured the 8.1 was only for windows 8.1 and server 2012 !